# Bootstrap not working properly with array props in VueJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am trying to get two divs to appear side by side when looping through props (which happen to be an array) in VueJS.
When I use a single element, it works fine. Immediately when I add the v-for tag it doesnt appear side by side anymore.

```
<div class="row">
    <div v-for="(data,index) in data" :key="index" class="col-12">
      <div v-if="data.image" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 image-div">
        <img class="image" :src="data.image" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
        <p class="title">{{data.title}}</p>
        <p class="description">{{data.description}}</p>
        <p class="bottom">
          <span class="left"><span class="tag">{{data.tag}}</span><span class="time"> | {{data.time}}</span></span>
          <span class="right"><v-icon>bookmark</v-icon><v-icon>share</v-icon></span>
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Above is the code i am using

Comment: I want both divs to appear side by side. Both the div that contains the image and the one after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're just missing the required `.row` for [grid nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting)

```html
<div v-for="(data,index) in data" :key="index" class="col-12">
  <div class="row"> <!--  this one -->
    <div v-if="data.image" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 image-div">
      <img class="image" :src="data.image" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
      <!-- etc -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```